# d3.js - transition interruption event?

Tags: events, d3.js, transition

I was wondering how to handle the fact that an interrupted transition within d3.js does not trigger an end event. As the API doc says

> Note that if the transition is superseded by a later-scheduled
>   transition on a given element, no end event will be dispatched for
>   that element; interrupted transitions do not trigger end events.
>   from: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#control

In my case transitions are triggered by user interaction. These transitions might be interrupted when the user triggers a new transition through mouse click. Let's say in the first transition an element was meant to fade out and be removed at the end of the transition. If this transition is interrupted the element will never be removed. I could disallow further user interaction during the time a transition happens yet that is not really what I want (particular as i have back and forward buttons which allow the user to click through previous states of my svg graph quickly ... ) Basically I would need an "Interruption Event"

Thanks

martin

Comment: In the code that triggers the new transition, you could check whether the previous one was completed and if not do what needs to be done, e.g. remove the element.

Comment: Thanks Lars i thought about that but it seems not really applicable if you have a network of possible transitions. The main problem here seems that if implemented in that way the handling of the interruption is then not declared with the transition itself.

Comment: There're no "interrupted" events generated unfortunately, so I don't see another way of dealing with this at the moment. Maybe open a feature request?

Comment: Yes it seems really something missing. I will wait a bit if somebody comes up with another solution before opening a feature request.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, where can I open a feature request, cant find it right now

Comment: Open an [issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues) on the github page.

Comment: Another way is to break your transition into multiple step. Then check whether to proceed to next transition. You can set global variable to keep track of state.

Comment: Thanks Phuoc for the suggestion. Following Lars suggestion I opened a feature request and Mike gave some positive feedback, I just have to find time to put a small example together as he asked for. I am convinced this event should be included ... ;-) https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1609

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no really satisfactory way to do this. A little bit painful workaround would be counting the number of transitions currently taking place and reasoning from that.

So, initialize:

```
var transitionCount = 0;
```

And whenever you schedule new transitions:

```
if ( transitionCount != 0 ) {
    // handle interrupted transitions here somehow
    transitionCount = 0;
}
var myTransition = selection.transition().... ; 
transitionCount += myTransition.size();
myTransition.each('end', function() { transitionCount --; });
```

If you can handle manually cleaning up interrupted transitions like this, this would be fine. Notice, that you can't use 'start' events to increment the counter as there is a delay between scheduling a transition and it being started so you'd get a race condition there.